# Pinterest API stop working

Tags: pinterest

We are offering Pinterest Pin scheduling features to our customer from last 1.5 years. We are suddenly started getting error response "Something went wrong on our end. Sorry about that." from today.

I have tried the Pinterest API explorer and also getting the same error message. The strange part is, though we are getting an error message, Pin is created with a broken image. I.e. https://in.pinterest.com/pin/573434965041286865/, When we try to open Image URL directly in browser i.e. https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d0/ad/c8/d0adc8520559848912b22f392eb339c1.jpg, it shows Access Denied error.

Is there any API changes or any other issue? We are currently passing the image as image_url parameters. We have tried sending a picture as multipart/form with image parameter too, but we are getting the same error.

here is the sample of our request.

URL: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/?access_token=&fields=id%2Clink%2Cnote%2Curl

Form Data:
image_url:http://d1ttb7iswciaye.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/slide1_img.png
note:Take one step forward, and then one more. It's all possible if you keep taking a small step forward#ows #success #possible
board:573435033743083706

Also, is there any way to connect to Pinterest support? Their help form at https://developers.pinterest.com/support/contact/ is also not working.

Comment: I have the same problem as you . The contact form and the API does not work for me too with same message

Comment: The contact form is broken, they offer no other way to reach out. There is not even a Twitter account, I believe. This is the most unprofessional large-scale service-company I've ever had to work with. The fact that we are polluting StackOverflow with this nonsense is absolutely not right, and yet I see no other way of them noticing the issues. And the [website](https://developers.pinterest.com/) only says: **API Status: Up**.

Comment: we can try contacting them here https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdrfZ7bPNk4Iwq0sDTm-RqdP93XroZPDtJ3vsFP_mHl54nYsw/viewform

Comment: Any people have news ?

Answer (score 0):

We are getting HTTP 500 error when trying to publish via their API.  Moreover, the Pins actually show up but [without a image](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/338544096975868351/).

I did find a contact/bug report at the bottom of [this page](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/?)

Answer (score 0):

Now the bug is resolved . My pin is created with photos .